# React not finding DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-dates

I just followed the steps to install react-dates to my project. I'm using their wrapper as a 'hello world' example but can't get it to run.

https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/examples/DateRangePickerWrapper.jsx

but on line 141 I'm getting the runtime error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. 
Check your code at DateRangePickerWrapper.jsx:141.
    in DateRangePickerWrapper (at GroupForm.js:253)
    in div (at GroupForm.js:204)
    in div (at GroupForm.js:201)
    in div (at FuseScrollbars.js:155)
    in FuseScrollbars (created by Connect(FuseScrollbars))
    in Connect(FuseScrollbars) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(FuseScrollbars)))
    in withRouter(Connect(FuseScrollbars)) (created by
```

I've tried not using the wrapper and simply importing and using DateRangePicker directly, Setting the parameters of the dates from strings to moment() to PropTypes null.

in my index.js I have import 'react-dates/initialize'; import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

but I feel like I'm not getting it initialized correctly. Maybe my initialize import isn't being run and therefor it can't find the component name?

This is a project created with 'create-react-app'

Comment: are you using exact code from the link? How to you export DateRangePickerWrapper? line 7 suggests that you should use "export default" and not simple "export" for you component.

Comment: I've simply hit save on the raw file and placed it in my project. The export is the final line of the file 'export default DateRangePickerWrapper;'

I THINK it may have something to do with the import 'react-dates/initialize'; not being run properly? It's in my index.js at the root of my project though

Comment: my index.js has
    import 'react-dates/initialize';
    import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
    import 'babel-polyfill'
    import 'typeface-muli';
    ...more imports...
    ReactDOM.render(
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Auth>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <FuseAuthorization routes={routes}>

So I would think that'd be the right location